# How to send parameters to paypal by server side

Tags: asp.net, forms, paypal, paypal-ipn

Good evening,
I have developed an IPN listener in aspx that works nice but I'm sending the parameters of subscriptions or buying items, client side, by form.
I would like to send the parameters to paypal in server side, to avoid frauds.
I have looked for on paypal site and around but I didnt understand how can I do it, can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Any server-side integration will support sending parameters on the server side. Which server-side integration do you want to use?

If you need recommendations, start with this front-end pattern for the UI: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Its fetch calls to `/demo...` need to be replaced with calls to actual endpoints on your server.

See how to implement v2/orders on your server at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

You will need the transaction setup API to return an orderID, and you will need to capture a transaction when called from the onApprove.

---

Once you get everything working for the happy path, don't neglect to [handle funding source failures](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/) -- so that if the capture fails on the server end when e.g. a payer's first card is declined, this is propagated back to the UI and they can just select a different one.

Comment: At the last I'm trying with SDK Paypal.dll, I have opened another post where I explain everything, thank you very much!